# How to solve this Towers of Hanoi variation

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I have been struggling to figure out how to solve a variation of Towers of Hanoi that I came across which has the constraint that **every move should involve the intermediate peg**. Below is the code for the regular Towers of Hanoi with out the constraint:

```
   public void Transfer(int numberOfDisks, Stack<int>[] pegs, int @from, int to, int use)
   {
       if (numberOfDisks > 0)
       {
           Transfer(numberOfDisks - 1, pegs, @from, use, to);

           pegs[use].Push(pegs[@from].Peek());
           pegs[@from].Pop();

           Console.WriteLine("Move disk: " + numberOfDisks + " from P" + @from + " to P" + to);

           Transfer(numberOfDisks - 1, pegs, use, to, @from);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
1. move smallest for 2 moves in 1 direction.
2. move other token (only possible token) by 1 move
3. goto point 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty easy to solve using a breadth-first search on a suitable graph in mind. Note that I say in mind because I wouldn't actually build the graph in memory. Now, start with the initial state represented by the first vertex. Then, for every allowed move, create an edge. If the resulting state wasn't visited yet, add it to the FIFO of vertices to visit... Basically it's a BFS without anything special, I hope you get the point, otherwise find a tutorial explaining BFS in detail.

Note that I'm not convinced that with this additional rule the game still can be solved, but even that should be easy to prove with that approach.